# How do I make my button go away and How do i implement my code after a button is pressed?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, timer

Im just starting out and have made a timer and stuff succesfully but now wanted to make a GUI since its not that straight forward and I want to have a good project.
I want to know how to remove a button after I press it and how to start my timer code after i take an entry for how long I want my timer to last. Here is my timer code:

```
import time
from playsound import playsound
a = int(input("How long would you like your time to be(In Minutes): "))
with alive_bar() as bar: 
    b = a * 60
    time.sleep(b)
    bar()
playsound(r"C:\Users\shavi\Music\mixkit-arcade-retro-game-over-213.wav")
print("done"
```

and here is my gui code

```
from tkinter import *
#First creating my window
timer = Tk()

#My window name and dimension
timer.title("My Timer")
timer.geometry('400x200')
#My Command
def clicked():
    lbl.configure(text = "Starting Timer")
    
#Label text
lbl = Label(timer, text ="Start a timer?")
lbl.grid()
#Button
button = Button(timer, text = "Yes",
                command=clicked,)
button.grid(column=2, row=0)
#Running 
timer.mainloop()
```

I tried using the .after but cant figure it out pleae help me figure this out

Comment: Do you want to show your timer on gui?

Comment: Yes I do want to open my timer on GUI

Comment: and also, will the music be played for the entire time?

Comment: Well when the timer ends I want the sound to play